# While using Windows Form application, unable to save first record to sql database, while subsequent record is being saved

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, winforms, desktop-application

I am practicing Windows Form application. Using Group box to enable all the textbox after clicking Add new button. When i click the save button, I am unable to save the first record, while the subsequent record is being saved. I am using  tableadaptor, bindingsource to connect and update table and dataset.

my SQL database has ID as a primary key and marked as identity with auto increment. When I click

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.bindingSource1.EndEdit();
        //-----------------------------
        int r;
        r=this.sa_In_LettersTableAdapter1.Update(this.letters1.Sa_In_Letters);
        if (r > 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(r.ToString()+" Recored is Saved.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sorry! Recored is not Saved.");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
    }

    enable_add_edit_delete_btn();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `sa_In_LettersTableAdapter1.Update`() code? Looks as if you might need to use the `Debugger` to step thru it

Comment: Hello,
it is a ready to use control available in visual studio for desktop application. simply need to configure with path.

Comment: You're using a table adapter so the update will use the state of the datarows in the data table this.letters1.Sa_In_Letters.  You don't show the code that adds the datarow to that table so we can't see where the issue is.  Debug your code and check the rowstate of the rows in the table prior to update.  If a row isn't 'Added' it won't create a new row in the database